# How many android apps are open source?

Tags: iphone, android, open-source

I know that the android plattform is open source. What I am interested in is the share of open source Android apps, thus developers that realease their own apps under a open source license.

Does anybody have an idea, how to get this information?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This post can give you a fair idea of the Open Source Software Projects of android

```
                                              New     Total OSS
                                            Projects    Mobile     Growth
OSS Projects Associated with a Platform      2009      Projects   '08-'09
-----------------------------------------  ---------- ---------- ---------
Android                                           224        357       168%
iPhone                                             76        252        43%
Windows Mobile                                     75        248        43%
Symbian                                            17        140        14%
Palm                                               10        527         2%
Maemo                                               9         27        50%
BlackBerry                                          4         39        11%
                                           ---------- ---------- ---------
     Sub Total                                    415       1590        35%
                                           ---------- ---------- ---------
Other OSS Mobile Projects                         488       1617        43%
                                           ---------- ---------- ---------
Total                                             903       3207        39%
                                           ---------- ---------- ---------
```

This table has been taken from [here](http://www.marketwire.com/press-release/Android-Wins-Over-Open-Source-Mobile-Developers-Growing-3x-Faster-Than-iPhone-According-1132346.htm)

[This](http://www.networkworld.com/community/node/60637?source=nww_rss) maybe worth reading too.

You can browse loads of Open Source Android Projects [here](http://code.google.com/hosting/search?q=label%3aAndroid)

Comment: You mentioned that there are 252 open source iPhone projects. Do you have links to them? Thanks!